# Unmarshalling xml to modal class failed using JAXB in java

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to map this xml into my modal class using JAXB. I have searched many solutions. But somehow for this one nothing is working. Everytime on mapping this xml to my model class  I am getting

> 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

```
<body>
    <i>
        <f name="name">test name</f>
        <f name="address">test address</f>
        <f name="phone">test phone</f>
    </i>
</body>
```

This is my model class

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "body")
    public class body {

        // XmLElementWrapper generates a wrapper element around XML representation
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "i")
        // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
        @XmlElement(name = "f")
        private ArrayList<f> f;

        public ArrayList<f> getF() {
            return f;
        }

        public void setF(ArrayList<f> f) {
            this.f = f;
        }            

        @XmlRootElement(name = "f")
        public static class f {

            String name;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how i am simply accessing:

```
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXml));
    // map xml to model class in jaxb
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Modal.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Modal modal = (Modal) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);
```

What am I missing? And further is there a way to access value of "f" node? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the complete error message (not just the part "1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions"). It tells you what you're doing wrong with the JAXB annotations. If you don't understand the error message, someone will be able to tell you what it means. My guess is that it is not allowed to have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the nested class `f` (why did you add it there?).

Comment: thanks i thought it was the complete error message. After seeing full error message I fixed it.